# Best object type for dynamic number of views on iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, nsmutablearray, uicollectionview

I have a website I am trying to convert to an iPad application.  I am new to iPad/iPhone development and I am not sure what type of object is the best to use.  The website is http://www.distripplanner.com.  If you look at section #3 (Choose Your Restaurants), the number of rows changes dynamically with number of days for the trip - with a max of 30 days.

My application is set up as a single-view application and I have my main view set up as a Scroll View (to scroll the page when the user chooses enough days) and the top portion of the application is completed.

I have tried to set up the view as a UICollectionView but did not get very far as it did not appear to be right object type.

I am currently working with an array of UIViews but the solution does not seem to be very optimized.  In the initial application load I am looping through 30 (max number of days for a trip) and creating a view (no sub objects yet) for each day.  I place the view based on calculations of the array index.

I do not add the subview to the main view if the array index is greater than the number of days for travel.  My plan was to add more (already created) subviews when the user adds days to their trip and removing (hiding) the subview if the user reduces the number of days of their trip.

This approach just does not seem like a good solution and I am at a loss s to what type of view or object to use for this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.